# Flex Drag and resize

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I need  to draw Line, Circle, and rectangle by mouse drag on canvas and then i need to to move and resize the drawn shapes.
How i can perform this in flex as i am new on this platform.
Please suggest me the method or refer any example with source to make it understand to me.
Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such native feature in Flex. But, there are a couple of options, commercial and not:

http://www.rogue-development.com/objectHandles.html (free)
http://www.flashcomguru.com/components/flex_whiteboard/whiteboard_demo/ (payed)

You can do it by hand, if you wish, it's not very hard. I advice you to use Degrafa (http://degrafa.org/) for the actual drawing since it is way easier than native drawing API and it is opensource.

Comment: Wow it really works...
Thanks artemb for such a nice explanation and a kind help..

Comment: Hi artemb, i would like to ask one more thing that when i use the source code for the whiteboard flex application i get the following error: 
"Unable to locate specified base class 'Whiteboard.WhiteboardManager' for component class 'Whiteboard.Whiteboard'. Can u help me in this Thanks in advance."

Comment: Sorry, but no. I've never used it.